# Creating multiple entries based on a value in a separate table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel table with multiple elements, each one with different fields.
One of the fields indicates "number of variations".

I have then a separate table that should contain all the variations, and I want to automatize this process.

Is there a way I can automatically fill a table's rows with a number of entries that depend on the "number of variations" value?

Example follows:
given this table:

| sku | number of variants |
| --- | --- |
| element1 | 2 |
| element2 | 5 |

should produce this table

| variant |
| --- |
| element1_1 |
| element1_2 |
| element2_1 |
| element2_2 |
| element2_3 |
| element2_4 |
| element2_5 |

Any help would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with a couple of helper columns:

- cumulative sum in your original table: `=SUM($B$1:B1)`
- creating row for each item: `=SEQUENCE(SUM(Table1[count]),1,0,1)`
- tracking current item: `=MATCH(E2,Table1[cumulative],1)`
- output: `=INDEX(Table1[sku],F2)&"_"&(E2-INDEX(Table1[cumulative],F2)+1)`

[image]

Comment: That worked wonders, thanks a lot!